# Как проверить сколько памяти съел EhCache?

Tags: java, spring, кэширование, log4j, ehcache

Использую org.ehcache, и столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу узнать сколько ehcache съел памяти, что бы вывести в консоль, буду благодарен за помощь.
использую spring 4.1.6, org.ehcache 3.0.3

Comment: а как вы создаете кэш?

Answer (score 0):

Я плохо знаком с `api`, но порывшись в исходниках, нашел следующее. Если `cache` является *on-heap*, то достучаться до занимаемого размера можно следующим образом:

в классе `Ehcache` есть закрытое поле:

```
private final Store<K, V> store;
```

в классе `OnHeapStore`, который реализует интерфейс `Store` содержится поле

```
private volatile Backend<K, V> map;
```

а вот у интерфейса `Backend` есть несколько интересных методов:

```
/**
 * Returns the computed size in bytes, if configured to do so
 *
 * @return the computed size in bytes
 */
 long byteSize();

/**
 * Returns the natural size, that is byte sized if configured, count size otherwise.
 *
 * @return the natural size
 */
long naturalSize();
```

Смею, предположить, что именно эти методы вам и нужны.

Comment: не то(( это какой то размер пула, да и когда я добавляю кеш, то результат не меняется. Да и по этому методу getSize всех кешов какой то красивый (1000, 50, 100, 2000), а учитывая сколько у меня там данных, как то маленькие результаты.

Comment: ок, обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, я посмотрел ваш вариант, и без понятия как докопаться до этих полей(  и там много классов пакетных.

Comment: @Elizar reflection